# É possível abrir janelas geradas a partir do netbeans no Window Builder?

Tags: java, swing, eclipse, netbeans, window-builder

Eu migrei alguns projetos em [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) do netbeans com janelas geradas pelo GUI-Builder para o Eclipse, mas o Window Builder não consegue gerar o design da tela lendo arquivos `.java` criados pelo netbeans.

É possível fazer o Window Builder renderizar corretamente as telas criadas no Gui-Builder dos Netbeans?

Comment: Só por curiosidade, eu vi em outras perguntas você falando sobre ter migrado. Você achou mais vantagem no eclipse ou algo que não tinha no Netbeans? Pergunto porque eu uso só o Netbeans também

Comment: @Sorack digamos que foi por "livre e espontânea pressão" :/

Comment: hahaha beleza, então acho que vou continuar no Netbeans, eu acho que depois de decorar os atalhos eu ia perder muito rendimento se mudasse de IDE. Se bem que pra JS eu uso o Webstorm com os padrões de hotkeys do Netbeans. Mas beleza, valeu por responder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segunda [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40664030/5524514) obtida no SOEn, não é possível, devido a forma que cada IDE gera esses arquivos que manipulam as telas. A solução seria reescrever todas as telas, mas não foi necessário. Consegui abrir a tela pela própria classe `.java`, através de um macete de alterar a forma como o window builder gera os códigos da tela, quando se está criando através do *drag 'n drop*.